Default format for pasting date/time into Excel?
When pasting dates and times into excel (i.e. 9/4/2024 11:35 am), the format applied just displays the time.   Is there a way to change this default?   I've never had a reason to use this format myself and always have to select the columns and change the format manually.   Is there a way to change this default behavior to a different format?
This happens when the results have a date format that includes partial seconds, for example '2024-09-03 21:10:00.8'.   Unfortunately for me people are always asking me to query details from a SQL Server that uses datetime and therefore the results I need to copy and paste are in this format, and they like to receive the results in Excel.  My normal workflow is to research an issue by running queries in SSMS and paste the results into excel.

I'm afraid it will be difficult to change Excel's default behavior.
However, you can redefine the cell format using the Change event.
Try this event macro. Alternatively, adjust the formats to your needs.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Target
        If (IsNumeric(cell) Or IsDate(cell)) And _
        (cell.NumberFormat = "mm:ss.0" _
        Or cell.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm") Then
            If cell.Value > 1 Then
                cell.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss.0"
            Else
                cell.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss.0"
        End If
    End If
    Next cell
    Target.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub

It is currently working on the entire sheet in which it was defined. You can limit the range to a selected portion of the worksheet.

Thanks, that is very helpful.   I should be able to write a macro and add a button to format the whole worksheet after pasting my data which is much easier.   Calling AutoFit is a nice touch.   I'll accept in a couple days if nobody answers with a way to change the default.

As you state, cells can be specifically formatted to display date-time with seconds, but that is not the default format. The default date-time format is taken from Region settings. However, there appears to be no way to add time to either short or long date format in the Region settings dialog.
Instead, format a blank Excel worksheet as desired, displaying date-time as you want, and save it as an Excel template, with .XLTX extension. Set that as the default template.
